# How can i copy app data to sdcard in android programatically?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am doing an app to backup and restore all user installed apps in android device. I am able to backup apk files of all apps that user selected to backup. Now i have to backup the data files of the app along with apk file.

i am trying something like this

```
public void copyDbToSdcard(String packageName) {
    InputStream myInput;
    String dbpath = "/data/"+packageName+"/databases/";
    String sdpath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();

    try {

        File exist=new File(Environment.getDataDirectory()+dbpath);
        System.out.println("1 "+ exist.exists());

        // Set the output folder on the Scard
        File directory = new File(sdpath + "/Back");
        // Create the folder if it doesn't exist:
        if (!directory.exists()) {
            directory.mkdirs();
        }
        // Set the output file stream up:
        myInput = new FileInputStream(Environment.getDataDirectory()
                + dbpath);

        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(directory.getPath()
                + "/refuel_db");

        // Transfer bytes from the input file to the output file
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);    
        }
        // Close and clear the streams

        myOutput.flush();

        myOutput.close();

        myInput.close();

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Backup Done Succesfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {


        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am getting error log as

`EACCES (Permission denied)` on line

`myInput = new FileInputStream(Environment.getDataDirectory()+ dbpath);`

I already gave READ and WRITE permissions in manifest file

Comment: You are not allowed to read the private data of other apps unless they set a world read permission on it.  You are also misconstructing the path (dbpath is absolute, so use it alone), but that doesn't matter since it would not work even if correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `/sdcard` in

```
String dbpath = "/sdcard/"+packageName+"/databases/";
```

instead of the /data because it belong to the "internal storage".

Comment: @Victor instead of the `Environment.getDataDirectory()` try using the `Enrivornment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`.

Comment: This is not the problem

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File myDir = new File(root + dbpath);
```

**And Add this to your manifest file**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Hope it Helps :)

Comment: where should i keep these java lines ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the problem

Comment: String sdpath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();(Replace this with  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(); )
and in  File directory = new File(sdpath + "/Back");
instead of "/back" replace it with dbpath

Answer (score 0):

```
private static String audioFilePath;
```

After layout Layout

```
audioFilePath =Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/abcd";
File abcd=new File(audioFilePath);
abcd.mkdirs();
```

for your problem..........

but u should made Directory in sd card name of abcd

Comment: This is not the problem